# Running Commands for Wifi at Startup

Tags: wireless, startup, automation, iwlwifi

I have just found a way to get my wifi to work using these commands:

```
sudo rmmod iwldvm
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

I would rather not type these in every time I log onto my computer. I was wondering how I might get these commands to run automatically when I log in. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than running the commands on login, it would usually be better practice to configure the kernel modules at boot time via files in the /etc/modprobe.d directory.

The names of the files are arbitrary (although they should have a .conf suffix) but it is a good idea to make them relate to the module in an obvious way e.g.

- create a file */etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-iwldvm.conf* containing the line

  ```
  blacklist iwldvm
  ```
- create a file */etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf* containing the line

  ```
  options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
  ```

The iwlwifi.conf file may exist already (if you have configured other options previously) - if so just append the new option rather than creating a new file. The changes will take effect when you reboot.