# Alternative to running rmmod and modprobe at every boot

Tags: mouse, touchpad, modprobe

My touchpad isn't properly recognized unless I manually run

```
rmmod psmouse
modprobe psmouse
```

at every boot. Surely there must be a better way?

Note: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399239/running-commands-for-wifi-at-startup) seems related, but in this case it's adding particular setting that does the trick. In mine there's no extra parameter to add.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `/etc/modules`, one module per line.

Comment: `psmod` is already loaded at boot; it's the specific sequence of unloading and then reloading it that makes the touchpad work.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu versions prior to 16.04, one could have simply added those lines to file `/etc/rc.local`, where it would have been picked up by startup services.

Since then, systemd only offered to launch this file as backwards compatibility clutch. Unix.SE question [How to write startup script for SystemD?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47695/68623) nicely summarises how to accomplish "just run my script once during boot, before I login".

The question shows more options, but for the simple case that is only 1-2 lines, one could write it like this:

1. Create a file in folder `/etc/systemd/system` named `<name-of-your-service>.service`.
   I chose `fix-touchpad.service`.
2. Fill it with the following contents. The actual payload is in line `ExecStart` passe as an argument to `/bin/sh`:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/fix-touchpad.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "rmmod psmouse && modprobe psmouse"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. Reboot the system.
4. Check the status of your new service using `sudo systemctl status fix-touchpad.service`:

```
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fix-touchpad.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2021-11-01 10:29:19 CET; 31min ago
   Main PID: 654 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 4504)
     Memory: 0B
        CPU: 0
     CGroup: /system.slice/fix-touchpad.service

Nov 01 10:29:19 my-machine systemd[1]: Starting fix-touchpad.service...
Nov 01 10:29:19 my-machine systemd[1]: Finished fix-touchpad.service.
```