# "Wi-Fi networks not ready" in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. After installing it, I cannot connect to wifi. It is saying "Wi-Fi networks not ready".

Here is the script output you have asked

```
##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: yes
   Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no

 ##### lsmod #############################

 iwldvm                233472  0
 mac80211              737280  1 iwldvm
 iwlwifi               200704  1 iwldvm
 cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
 ideapad_laptop         24576  0
 sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
 mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
 video                  40960  3 i915,ideapad_laptop,nouveau
 wmi                    20480  3 ideapad_laptop,mxm_wmi,nouveau

 ##### interfaces ########################

 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 ##### ifconfig ##########################

 enp7s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]>  
           inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: 2600:8804:1080:1d0:8b2c:f7ce:e6a3:ab8d/64         
 Scope  :Global  
      inet6 addr: 2600:8804:1080:1d0:4d45:dcd3:e882:b41c/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2600:8804:1080:1d0:4947:4e92:1188:1336/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::f9cb:6be0:10ac:4937/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2600:8804:1080:1d0:cc2e:e7fe:725:14a4/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:7676 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:7848190 (7.8 MB)  TX bytes:659611 (659.6 KB)
      Interrupt:16 

 wlp8s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp8s0' [IF2]>  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

 ##### iwconfig ##########################

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp8s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off


 ##### route #############################

 Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use   Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0   enp7s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp7s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp7s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

NetworkManager

Running:

root      8052     1  0 21:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager     --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp7s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet      PCIe
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tg3
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.137
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               sb
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp7s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     enp7s0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       c4a074d3-9e31-453a-   9c8 0-3871b56b5619
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager /ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1,0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   c4a074d3-9e31-453a-9c80-3871b56b5619 | enp7s0
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   bff8e195-f3a8-4b00-9dec-7f2ca92bd43f | Wired connection 1 
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.2/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             68.105.28.11
IP4.DNS[2]:                             68.105.29.11
IP4.DNS[3]:                             68.105.28.12
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1 
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                    

    requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = ubuntu
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       expiry = 1478903026
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.2
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 68.105.28.11 68.105.29.11 68.105.28.12
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2600:8804:1080:1d0:4947:4e92:1188:1336/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2600:8804:1080:1d0:cc2e:e7fe:725:14a4/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         2600:8804:1080:1d0:8b2c:f7ce:e6a3:ab8d/64
IP6.ADDRESS[4]:                         2600:8804:1080:1d0:4d45:dcd3:e882:b41c/64
IP6.ADDRESS[5]:                         fe80::f9cb:6be0:10ac:4937/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::5e8f:e0ff:fe59:474
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2001:578:3f::30
IP6.DNS[2]:                             2001:578:3f:1::30
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 2001:578:3f::30 2001:578:3f:1::30
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_preference = 0
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:1:0:1:1f:b3:d7:10:5c:8f:e0:59:4:74
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:35:41:54:c:db:6:c6:7e:ca:72:7b:88:54:bc:39:82

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp8s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] (Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-31-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               39.31.5.1 build 35138
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp8s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:08:00.0/net/wlp8s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Etc/UTC (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp7s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp8s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp7s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp8s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     6A40B68AAA6792A5BDEA010
depends:        mac80211,iwlwifi,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     2FFAEED0245CA1D97FE1E44
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     651BF6CBF283F6F817B8F3A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  476.521273] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[  476.521278] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[  476.521282] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00100040 | l2p_addr_match
[  476.521287] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  476.521291] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[  476.521296] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x0000F808 | flow_handler
[  476.521372] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Start IWL Event Log Dump: display last 5 entries
[  476.521400] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000000000:0x0000028c:0117
[  476.521417] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000000021:0x00000000:1208
[  476.521435] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000001002:0x00000001:0071
[  476.521452] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000001078:0x00000002:0071
[  476.521469] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000001084:0x00000000:0125
[  476.521818] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[  476.521836] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[  476.522471] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled (repeated 2 times)
[  476.530179] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
[  476.538580] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x82000000.
[  476.538592] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: CSR values:
[  476.538597] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: (2nd byte of CSR_INT_COALESCING is CSR_INT_PERIODIC_REG)
[  476.538607] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:        CSR_HW_IF_CONFIG_REG: 0X00c8330c
[  476.538617] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:          CSR_INT_COALESCING: 0X00000040
[  476.538690] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                     CSR_INT: 0X80000000
[  476.538699] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                CSR_INT_MASK: 0X00000000
[  476.538708] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:           CSR_FH_INT_STATUS: 0X40010000
[  476.538718] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                 CSR_GPIO_IN: 0X00000000
[  476.538730] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                   CSR_RESET: 0X00000000
[  476.538743] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                CSR_GP_CNTRL: 0X080403c5
[  476.538756] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                  CSR_HW_REV: 0X0000006c
[  476.538776] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:              CSR_EEPROM_REG: 0Xc63f3885
[  476.538795] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:               CSR_EEPROM_GP: 0X90000001
[  476.538808] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:              CSR_OTP_GP_REG: 0X00210801
[  476.538821] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                 CSR_GIO_REG: 0X00080046
[  476.538846] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:            CSR_GP_UCODE_REG: 0X00000000
[  476.538858] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:           CSR_GP_DRIVER_REG: 0X00000000
[  476.538871] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP1: 0X00000000
[  476.538882] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP2: 0X00000000
[  476.538901] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                 CSR_LED_REG: 0X00000018
[  476.538914] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:        CSR_DRAM_INT_TBL_REG: 0X00000000
[  476.538927] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:        CSR_GIO_CHICKEN_BITS: 0X27800200
[  476.538940] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:             CSR_ANA_PLL_CFG: 0X00880300
[  476.538958] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:      CSR_MONITOR_STATUS_REG: 0X53f7f757
[  476.538971] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:           CSR_HW_REV_WA_REG: 0X0001001a
[  476.538984] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:        CSR_DBG_HPET_MEM_REG: 0Xffff0000
[  476.539002] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: FH register values:
[  476.539030] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:         FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X233fe800
[  476.539056] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:        FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X0233bd60
[  476.539083] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                  FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X000000f8
[  476.539110] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:         FH_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X80801114
[  476.539134] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:          FH_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X000000fc
[  476.539155] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:            FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X07030000
[  476.539176] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:    FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X00000000
[  476.539198] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                FH_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X07ff0001
[  476.539219] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X00000000
[  476.539226] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 39.31.5.1 build 35138
[  476.539394] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  476.539399] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 5
[  476.539404] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000005 | SYSASSERT                   
[  476.539410] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00016E00 | uPc
[  476.539414] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00016E00 | branchlink1
[  476.539419] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00016E00 | branchlink2
[  476.539423] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink1
[  476.539427] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[  476.539432] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[  476.539436] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[  476.539440] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000616 | line
[  476.539445] iwlwienter code herefi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00018BCA | beacon time
[  476.539449] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000436 | tsf low
[  476.539454] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[  476.539458] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  476.539462] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x0000043A | time gp2
[  476.539467] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp3
[  476.539471] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x0001271F | uCode version
[  476.539476] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x0000006C | hw version
[  476.539480] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00C8330C | board version
[  476.539485] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | hcmd
[  476.539489] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00122000 | isr0
[  476.539493] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[  476.539498] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000002 | isr2
[  476.539502] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x004400C0 | isr3
[  476.539506] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  476.539511] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr_pref
[  476.539516] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00002BFE | wait_event
[  476.539521] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[  476.539528] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[  476.539533] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[  476.539537] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00100040 | l2p_addr_match
[  476.539542] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  476.539546] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[  476.539551] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: 0x0000F808 | flow_handler
[  476.539627] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Start IWL Event Log Dump: display last 5 entries
[  476.539655] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000000000:0x0000028c:0117
[  476.539673] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000000021:0x00000000:1208
[  476.539690] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000001003:0x00000001:0071
[  476.539707] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000001079:0x00000002:0071
[  476.539724] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0000001085:0x00000000:0125
[  476.540025] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[  476.540039] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Unable to initialize device.

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot or better yet,  http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos The 2nd link will send you to a page with an answer that includes a script that you can run to provide necessary info to help us diagnose your issue

Comment: Hi, Elder Geek uploaded the file as you asked

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/618283/is-iwlwifi-or-iwldvm-or-wext-the-wireless-driver

Comment: That didn't answer the question how to enable the wifi

Comment: Try `rfkill unblock all` if that doesn't activate your wifi try the commands listed in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/399239/running-commands-for-wifi-at-startup if that works you can make the changes permanent with the answer to the aformentioned question.  If all else fails perhaps we can get @chili555 to chime in on this one.

Comment: Any of those didn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `dpkg -l linux-image-4*` as I'm seeing ` /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko` in your output and I'm not sure if it's relevant (I don't have your hardware) but I do know the kernel  I'm running is `4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26` Have you tried `sudo apt update;sudo apt upgrade`? You can interpret the output with [this](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/status-dpkg-list/)

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same problem. I solve the problem by restarting the network manager.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: That didn't work in my case